# Selecting NOT NULL columns from a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table is having approximately 80 columns. I am performing the following query on the table.

`SELECT * FROM mobile_details WHERE id=4;`

It is confirmed that the above query will return only one row. I want to select only the columns which are not having value `NULL` or empty. How can I do this?

Note: A very inefficient way to do this is to put NOT NULL in every column while SELECTing. But I need a more efficient and effective way (either in PHP code or MySQL query).

Can I do something like this? `SELECT * FROM mobile_details WHERE id=4 AND mobile_details.* NOT NULL;`

I am using PHP + MySQL + Apache on CentOS server.

Comment: is itemid a foreign key? are you doing a left join on your query?

Comment: Short of writing code that runs inside the database, that you will then call, there is no way to have it not return all the columns you ask for, in your case you are asking that it return to you all columns.

Comment: @BookoFZEUS: `ID` is the primary key of the table. I am not doing any left join.

Comment: @BookOfZeus: Sorry for the confusion. `ITEMID` is nothing. I edited my question.

Comment: @iSubmitG see Ned Batchelder answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't change the list of columns programmatically in SQL.  There's no syntax for it.

Comment: Suppose I store the result in `$result`. How to do it efficiently in PHP?

Comment: @iSumitG: just check each column against null using === would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  You can do some trickery, but it's not worth it.  Why not just skip the null columns when you are processing the data?  It's easy enough to check for in PHP.  Also, you shouldn't use `SELECT *` in production.  Select just the columns you want and if you happen to want all of them, list them all.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it in php, use function `array_filter` to filter the null values.